# Android - set Sound Recorder mime type from Intent

Tags: android, cordova, android-intent, mime-types, audio-recording

I'm using Cordova to build my mobile app and I need to record sounds.
I'm using the media-capture plugin which launches the default android recorder app within this function:

```
private void captureAudio() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.RECORD_SOUND_ACTION);

        this.cordova.startActivityForResult((CordovaPlugin) this, intent, CAPTURE_AUDIO);
}
```

The problem is that after I get the file path and try to `getAudioVideoData` (which contains informations like "duration") the audio recording format (which is default to .amr) seems like cannot be parsed and throws an exception.

```
private JSONObject getAudioVideoData(String filePath, JSONObject obj, boolean video) throws JSONException {
        MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            player.setDataSource(filePath);
            player.prepare();
            obj.put("duration", player.getDuration() / 1000);
            if (video) {
                obj.put("height", player.getVideoHeight());
                obj.put("width", player.getVideoWidth());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Error: loading video file");
        }
        return obj;
}
```

I know that the problem is media format because on my older Android device, with 4.4.4, the Sound Recorder app has settings from where I can change file type and if I set it to .wav, than the `getAudioVideoData` works!

I have tried to add the following inside `captureAudio()` before `startActivityForResult()`:

```
intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ENTRY_CONTENT_TYPE, "audio/aac");
intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE, "audio/aac");
intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.CONTENT_TYPE, "audio/aac");
```

..but with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to influence the output of Sound Recorder app via intent, but I solved the main problem, which was that I couldn't read recorded audio file's metadata (duration property).

Fixed with this PR: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media-capture/pull/50